# Help with SharePoint calculated columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to get a calculated column to work, I have the first part working fine
=IF([Week Day]="Monday",[Week Ending]-6)
So if weekday is Monday then take 6 from week ending and that is todays date.

However when I try to add on the rest of the week days for IF Tuesday, IF Wednesday etc I get a failure.  Is anyone able to provide a little bit of steering?  Here is one the examples of what I have tried...

=IF(([Week Day]="Monday",[Week Ending]-6), IF([Week Day]="Tuesday",[Week Ending]-5-))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the if statements are nested and closed at the end of the formula:

```
=IF([Week day]="Monday",[Week Ending]-6,
IF([Week day]="Tuesday",[Week Ending]-5,
IF([Week day]="Wednesday",[Week Ending]-4,
IF([Week day]="Thursday",[Week Ending]-3,
IF([Week day]="Friday",[Week Ending]-2,
)))))
```

(untested but from a similar formula...)

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work, it comes back with an error...

Comment: JJD this did actually work in the end.  Had to be a single line and include a space after every comma (even though SharePoint removes these once the codes are applied.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Oh you're right, I forgot about the spaces and line breaks. Makes it much more readable but doesn't actually work in Sharepoint...